# Add an item to SQL and get auto incrementing id back immediately

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

I'm using the following code to add a entry to my SQL database.

```
$RQ1_string = "INSERT INTO automotive_RQ01_Information VALUES(NULL,'".$title."','".$description."')";
$RQ1_result = mysql_query($RQ1_string);
```

In the next line I need to use the value of the auto-incrementing ID(The NULL entry).

How can I get the ID from RQ1_result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use mysql_insert_id(). This can be assigned to a variable or outputted directly.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php